# Yii2: how to use different auth methods in API

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am working on API in Yii2, where I need to use different authentication methods for different actions.

How can I set `CompositeAuth` for `action1`, `action2` and `action3`, and `HttpBasicAuth` for `action4` and `action5`?

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'basicAuth' => [
            'class' => \yii\filters\auth\HttpBasicAuth::className(),
            'auth' => function ($username, $password) {
                $user = User::find()->where(['username' => $username])->one();
                if ($user->verifyPassword($password)) {
                    return $user;
                }
                return null;
            },
        ],
    ];
}
```

Comment: Try first following the Yii2 Authentication guide in https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/rest-authentication. If you get stuck in some point please give some example codes you are working to get better help.

Comment: Yes, i followed it, and i am able to use both authentication in different API controllers, but in my case i have to user 2 auth methods in same controller.

Comment: Here i have used Basic auth method but for some actions in same API controller i want to use Composite Auth method

Answer (score 2):

You can attach multiple auth behaviors and use [`only`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-actionfilter#$only-detail) property to specify list of actions which should be affected by each behavior:

```
public function behaviors() {
    return [
        'authentificator' => [
            'class' => \yii\filters\auth\CompositeAuth::className(),
            'authMethods' => [/* ... */],
            'only' => ['action1', 'action2', 'action3'],
        ],
        'basicAuth' => [
            'class' => \yii\filters\auth\HttpBasicAuth::className(),
            'auth' => function ($username, $password) {
                $user = User::find()->where(['username' => $username])->one();
                if ($user->verifyPassword($password)) {
                    return $user;
                }
                return null;
            },
            'only' => ['action4', 'action5'],
        ],
    ];
}
```

Comment: According documentation (https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/rest-authentication)  this must be below the key `authentificator`.
 I updated this in your post

Comment: @Radon8472 I reverted your change, as code seems to be incorrect. Key does not matter for behaviors, only content of array is important, as it is configuration for behavior (and it is incorrect after your change).

Comment: Hmm okay, thats strange. 
I documentation says it should be unter the authentificator key

Comment: I changed key for `CompositeAuth`, it should be less confusing now.